# List all jobs, which were running on a specific slave node

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, slave

On our Jenkins master a Multi-configuration project is used to spread a highly parallel task on many slaves which actually do the work.

Now I would like to list all jobs, which were running on a specific slave node. Is there a way to achieve this? I see only all matrix sub jobs for one matrix parent job in a big table. Or I can list the history of a single sub job. But if I want to get the connection to the node, where the job was running on, I always have to check the logs.

Comment: In terms of multi-configuration project, those "sub-jobs" are called "configurations". Could you please show us config of your axis in "Configuration Matrix" section (job configuration)?

Comment: Hi Vitalii, thank you for your comment. I'm not quite sure, why you need this information, because I'm just searching for a plugin, which lists the job history by a different point of view (sorted by nodes). But our configuration has one "Slaves" axis, which actually ensures, that the "matrix-configurations" (in my terms "sub-jobs" ;-)) are spread to slaves marked with a given label. In addition, we have five "User-defined" axes to vary our device configuration.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Description Setter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Description+Setter+Plugin) like the following:

[image]

Then you will have node label in the description of each build:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. Unfortunately I can not use this solution. We already use the description for an other purpose

Comment: @FlowReiSer Just let you know, description can have multiple values. But yes, that is not a perfect way to report.

Answer (score 2):

> Now I would like to list all jobs, which were running on a specific slave node.

I didn't find any existed plugin to solve the problem. But you can automate it a bit with a [Jenkins Script Console](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Script+Console).
Here is a simple groovy script that iterates through job's builds and checks whether that build was [built on](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/AbstractBuild.html#getBuiltOnStr()) a concrete node:

```
def jobs = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.items

nodeName = 'YOUR_NODE_NAME'

jobs.each { job ->
  urls = []
  job.builds.each { build ->
    nodeName == build.builtOnStr && urls << build.absoluteUrl
  }
  urls && println("${job.name}\n\t${urls.sort().join('\n\t')}")
}
```

Sample output:

```
JOB1    
    JENKINS_URL/job/JOB1/11/
JOB2
    JENKINS_URL/job/JOB2/59/
    JENKINS_URL/job/JOB2/60/
    JENKINS_URL/job/JOB2/61/
    ...
```

If you would like to go further, you could use it to prepare some clickable html report. First that comes to the mind is to send emails with [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin).

**Note:** that script will not work with `nodeName = 'master'`. This should be expected 'cause master, actually, is not a node.

Comment: Hi Vitalii, thank you for your help. I will use your solution, if I can not find any other way. It is definitively better than to check all the logs manually :-)

Comment: @Vitalii Elenhaupt, is there a way to list projects (not jobs have been run) currently restricted to a particular node? We want to get ride of some nodes, want to notify projects using these nodes.

Comment: If you get the `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: builtOnStr for class: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun` error, here is my "no so robust" solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/69473721/5374189

Answer (score 2):

I've solved it like this using the script console

```
for (item in hudson.model.Hudson.getInstance().getItems()) {
  if (item instanceof hudson.model.FreeStyleProject) {
    if (item.getAssignedLabel() != null && item.getAssignedLabel().getName() == 'master') {
      println(item.getName() + " " + item.getAssignedLabel())
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to answer "which node the job is assigned to", and does not work with pipeline jobs where node is assigned during run time.