# List all Jenkins builds grouped by node

Tags: jenkins, groovy, build

I would like to extract all jobs and group them by nodes. The goal of this is to have a list of builds to run a script and delete builds.

This is what I try to execute on the script:

```
def jobs = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.items
nodeName = 'YOUR_NODE_NAME'
jobs.each { job ->
  urls = []
  job.builds.each { build ->
    nodeName == build.builtOnStr && urls << build.absoluteUrl
  }
  urls && println("${job.name}\n\t${urls.sort().join('\n\t')}")
}
```

I'm getting an error and I have no ide why, this is the error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: builtOnStr for class: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error is quite clear. There is no property buindOnStr for object in variable build.

Comment: Hi! How could I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I solved this way:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import hudson.model.*

SimpleDateFormat dateTimeParser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
def jobs = Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob)
def nodeName = build.getEnvironment(listener).get('NODE_NAME')
def daysAgo = build.getEnvironment(listener).get('DAYS_AGO').toInteger()
def limitDate = new Date().minus(daysAgo)

if (nodeName == "") {
  println("Node name can't be empty")
  return 1
}

jobs.each { job ->
  urls = []
  job.getBuilds().each { build ->
    if (build.getTime() > limitDate && build.getLog().contains(nodeName)) {
        urls << "${dateTimeParser.format(build.startTimeInMillis)} | $build.absoluteUrl | $build.result"
      }
    }
    urls && println("${job.name}\n${urls.sort().join('\n')}")
}
```

I couldn't find a way to gather the node label, I ended up searching it in the log

It is a modified answer from this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/30909035/5374189

Comment: That is missing something for sure.
` No such property: build for class: Script1`
if you use Build, it will go a step forward, but not much further, listener not defined either.